# Android Studio Gradle Build Error Flamingo Version

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

Guys I keep getting this error "caused by org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfigiration$ArtifactResolveException: could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'." When ever I try to view the app using the virtual device. I deleted the Gradle files uninstalled Android studio then reinstalled it and downloaded Gradle files yet it didn't work Everytime it says Gradle Build failed. Please what should I do.

Uninstalling Android Studio and deleting old .Gradle files and reinstalling Android Studio and downloading Gradle files updating SDK and JDK still not working.

Comment: You are using a incompatible combination  version of Android gradle plugin version, and  Build version

Comment: Please further explain and how do I resolve it.

Comment: I've done that already and it didn't work not improve

Answer (score 1):

On the right side panel of the Android Studio , You can see a option called Gradle. Click on that. Then Toggle Offline.

[image: image of Gradle settings]

Comment: I have tried that, it didn't work.